# Bug in Export - known by Wolfram Support - upper plot margin depends on string length of upper horizontal axis label

Tags: plotting, graphics, bugs, export

**Bug introduced in 9.0 and persisting through 12.0 or later**

---

### **! See at bottom the answer by Wolfram Research.**

I am running *Mathematica* 10.3.

For test purposes I have used the following code:

```
plot = ListPlot[{{0.25, 0.25}, {0.5, 0.5}, {0.75, 0.75}}, 
   Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, Joined -> True, 
   AspectRatio -> 1, 
   FrameLabel -> {{"y (mm)", ""}, {"x (mm)", 
      "aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbccc"}}, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 40, 
     FontFamily -> "Calibri"}, ImageSize -> 800];

Export["F:\\export23.png", plot, "png"];
```

The upper plot margin depends on the length of the 4th string of `FrameLabel`.

Here are two images for comparison with a string length of 22 and 23 characters.
The red square area marks the additional margin which occurs for 23 character length and more.

[image]

> This problem does not! occur when the images are saved directly from
>   the notebook via "Save Graphic As ..."

What could be the reason?

**Answer from Wolfram Research- Technical Support:**

> I have reproduced this problem where Export creates too much
>   whitespace in your plot.  I have filed a report with our developers so
>   that they can look into the issue further and potentially fix it in
>   some future version of Mathematica.  Your contact information has been
>   appended to the report so that you can be notified when this issue is
>   fixed.

---

george2079 wrote:
Edit: simple example. Make the label string longer than about 20 char and the margin grows (for no evident reason )

```
ImportString[
 ExportString[
  ListPlot[{{0.25, 0.25}, {0.5, 0.5}, {0.75, 0.75}}, Frame -> True, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}},
   Joined -> True, AspectRatio -> 1, 
   FrameLabel -> {{"y (mm)", ""}, {"x (mm)", 
      StringJoin@RandomChoice[CharacterRange["a", "z"], 20]}},
   BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 40, 
     FontFamily -> "Calibri"}, ImageSize -> 2000], "PNG"], "PNG"]
```

Comment: see if you can reproduce the issue without using dynamic.

Comment: I can reproduce, from what I can tell, it has to do with the length of the title- it seems to add padding when you get over n chars

Comment: Including `ImagePadding` seems to work. Try adding `ImagePadding -> {{All, All}, {All, 50}}`

Comment: Looks like a bug, please report to WRI (support@wolfram.com)

Comment: indeed only the length is responsible for the increasing upper margin ... I am changing therefore my question

Comment: Reproduced with versions 10.0.1, 10.2 and 10.3 on Win7 x64. With version 8.0.4 both plots have no extra space, with version 9.0.1 both have extra space, with versions 10.x the first plot has no extra space but the second has. So I think the bug is introduced in version 9.

Comment: Was this somewhere documented? I have informed Wolfram.

Comment: @mrz At least we have here serious inconsistency between what is displayed in the FrontEnd (no extra space) and what is `Export`ed. Also this behavior is certainly unexpected because there is no need for extra space and in version 8.0.4 it worked correctly. So it is reasonable to count it as a bug. Please post here the responce from WRI when you receive it and thank you for reporting!

Comment: @Alexey Popkov: I did get already an answer ... see above

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a bug introduced in version 9. A workaround is to export the corresponding `Cell` expression:

```
Export["export23.png", Cell@BoxData@ToBoxes[plot]]
```

> [image: plot]

An alternative is to use `RawBoxes`:

```
Export["export23.png", RawBoxes@ToBoxes[plot]]
```

... or `ExpressionCell`:

```
Export["export23.png", ExpressionCell[plot]]
```

Checked with versions 9.0.1 and 10.3.